# Removing double quotes from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

How would I remove double quotes from a String?

For example:  I would expect `"abd` to produce `abd`, without the double quote.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
line1 = line1.replaceAll("\"(\\b[^\"]+|\\s+)?\"(\\b[^\"]+\\b)?\"([^\"]+\\b|\\s+)?\"","\"$1$2$3\"");
```

Comment: `string.Replace("\"", "");`? I have no idea what you're trying to do with that bigass regex.

Comment: wats with the `line1 = line1.replaceAll("\"(\b[^\"]+|\s+)?\"(\b[^\"]+\b)?\"([^\"]+\b|\s+)? \"","\"$1$2$3\"");` ? is that you regex to remove quotes?

Comment: Remember that the original string is NOT changed. It returns new string with RegEx  applied. So this is must:
String ln;
ln = line.replaceAll("[\"]", "");

Answer (score 154):

You can just go for `String` [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method.-

```
line1 = line1.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: hmmm.... shouldn't it be double backslash ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild no backslash is the escape character. Using double backslash will give you a compilation error.

Answer (score 26):

Use replace method of string like the following way:

```
String x="\"abcd";
String z=x.replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(z);
```

**Output:**

```
abcd
```

Answer (score 25):

```
String withoutQuotes_line1 = line1.replace("\"", "");
```

have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)