# How do I remove the " from the string

Tags: java

My line of code looks like this:

```
String[] cit = line.split(",");
```

The line looks like this:

```
Birth Certificate”,”<f>Record Type:>Record Type: >>>Birth Certificate>>e>
```

cit then has 2 values:

the first = Birth Certificate”
the second = ”Record Type:>Record Type: >>>Birth Certificate>>e>

How do I get rid of the " at the end of the first and the " at the start of the second?

Thanks
Roger

Comment: Please post your attempt and any stacktrace produced.

Comment: So what have you attempted so far? This is not a code writing service. We are not here to do your job for you. You show what you've attempted, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: [`String.replace(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing double quotes from a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316394/removing-double-quotes-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have special speech marks so this will work.

```
    String line = "Birth Certificate”,”<f>Record Type:>Record Type: >>>Birth Certificate>>e>";
    String[] cit = line.split("”,”");
    System.out.println(cit[0]);
    System.out.println(cit[1]);
```

If you want to use standard speech marks then you can use this.

```
    String[] cit = line.split("\",\"");
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. For some reason I can not get this to work String[] cit = line.split("\",\""); It causes a compile error but this did work String[] cit = line.split("”,”"); Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Please add stacktrace and error messages to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around the double quotes like this:

`String[] cit = line.split('","');`

In your original code, the `split` only cuts the code at the comma, and keeps the quotation marks. By putting single quotes, you include the quotation marks as part of the split.

Comment: This is Java, not Groovy!

Comment: Cannot do that in Java.

Comment: Oh. Sorry! (thanks Klitos + Sirish for pointing out my stupid mistake!)