# regular expression to get string in between special charecters

Tags: java, regex

Iam trying to get the string `october` from the string `["october"]`
i tried with replace method

```
 tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); \\ it prints "october"
```

i cant replace quote with `""`.

```
 tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

not replacing quotes prints     `\"october\"`

But i prefer to use a single code

using `regex` code how can i get the string with out `quotes` and `square bracket`

Comment: Do you want to parse JSON? Then don't use regular expressions, use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: you should follow the advise of @RolandIllig but you can use  `tagNo.replaceAll("\\[\\W*(\\w+)\\W*\\]", "$1")` OR you can use this for special characters `tagNo.replaceAll("\\[\"(.*)\"\\]", "$1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly correct your regex. You haven't put any rule for removing double quote. Try using this,

```
tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("(\\[|\"|\\])+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
```

Comment: I think this would be the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("\\[\"", "");
 tagNo = tagNo.replaceAll("\"\\]", "");
```

Refer [Java replace all square brackets in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442162/java-replace-all-square-brackets-in-a-string)

[Removing double quotes from a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316394/removing-double-quotes-from-a-string-in-java)